# PDF Clown does not render text

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfclown

I use [PDF Clown](https://pdfclown.org/) to create PDF files containing text and different shapes. Saving the files brings the desired result. But when I print the pages or render them to bitmaps, only the shapes are visible and the text elements are missing.

I tried already different versions of the library with multiple files, always getting the same result.

Maybe someone can give me a hint on this issue.

EDIT:

This is a simplified form of the source code I use (with same result as described above; see the image at the end):

```
File file = new File();

Document document = file.Document;
document.PageSize = PageFormat.GetSize(PageFormat.SizeEnum.A4, PageFormat.OrientationEnum.Portrait);

Page page = new Page(document);
document.Pages.Add(page);

PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);


//draw a rectangle
composer.SetFillColor(DeviceRGBColor.Get(System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon));
composer.DrawRectangle(new RectangleF(30, 42, 300, 32));
composer.Fill();


//draw some text
composer.SetFillColor(DeviceRGBColor.Get(System.Drawing.Color.Black));
composer.SetFont(new StandardType1Font(document, StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Courier, true, false), 32);
composer.ShowText("Hello World!", new PointF(32, 48));
composer.Flush();


//save the file
file.Save(@"..\document.pdf", SerializationModeEnum.Standard);


//and print it
Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
renderer.Print(file.Document, false);
```

Result of the above code (the printed version was created with virtual printer *Adobe PDF*; also tested with *XPS Document Writer*):

[image]

Comment: You might want to share a sample to allow others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Could it be, that text Rendering is not implemented yet at all?

Comment: I tried the same using the Java version, and here not even the rectangle is rendered, I get a pure white page. So yes, rendering seems not yet to be properly implemented.

Answer (score 4):

(I don't have enough points to add a comment so I put this comment as an answer.)  If you look in the source for the RenderingSample class, you will see this comment:

> This sample demonstrates how to render a PDF page as a raster image.
>       Note: rendering is currently in pre-alpha stage; therefore this sample is
>       nothing but an initial stub (no assumption to work!).

I don't think Stephano Chizzolini got around to finishing it.

There is another NuGet download, PDFClown.Net version 2.0.0, by Matthieu.  It has tags for  PDF-To-Image, Rasterizer and PDF, but I have not been able to get it to work either.  I cannot find documentation for it.  Inspection of the properties for the downloaded NuGET assembly shows version 0.1.2.0 instead of 2.0.0.